# Django: Create a site with subsites

Tags: python, django

I would like to create a site in django that follows the following example.

```
example.com
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
```

example.com being the main site. Users should be able to login from example.com to access the other subsites. What's the best way to accomplish this or has someone done something similar they'd like to share to help me solve this headache I'm having.

They should have different apps per subdomain

Comment: You already have the subdomains? Or are you asking how to get them? Because Django won't solve that for you, it will just work with your subdomains. You need to contact your webhost to create new subdomains.

Comment: http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/multi-tennancy-in-django-using-subdomains/

Comment: @bisera You probably mean this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN

Comment: What I mean is i want to create a site that share the code base but they have different apps per domain

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to have each site share the same database for at least some of the functionality; that is, some common elements are associated with one or more sites using the `ManyToManyField`.

See Django's documentation for [associating content with multiple sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#associating-content-with-multiple-sites).